# Calculation goes wrong when I started using SeekBar

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, seekbar

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView ePrice;
TextView InputPrice;
TextView InputPercent;
TextView ePercent;

private SeekBar volumeControl = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /** Remove title bar */
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** Hide Auto Keyboard */
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    /** Hide Auto Keyboard End here */

    InputPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ePrice);
    InputPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ePercents);

    ePrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ePrice);
    ePercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ePercents);
```

Here is my SeekBar. Before this SeekBar I have been using EditText and every thing was ok but after i started using this SeekBar the SECOND result is so weird!!

```
    SeekBarPer = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volume_bar);
    SeekBarPer.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressChanged = 0;
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
            progressChanged = progress;
            TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ePercents);
            label.setText(""+progressChanged);
        }
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
```

what I have:

One EditText up One TextView under the SeekBar and Two another TextView are down to show the result of calculating the Price and the Percent! The First result is going well but the second is NOT!
For example if i calculate 30 dollars minus 50% i got the first result 15 and the second one 35.

What I want:

Just to correct the second result

Here is the Calculation:

```
    // show the price to get 
final TextView tR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewResult);
// show the price to pay 
final TextView tRpay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewResultPay);

Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            double price = Double.parseDouble(ePrice.getText().toString());
            double percent = Double.parseDouble(ePercent.getText().toString());

            double pri = (price / 100.0f) * percent;;
            double per = percent  * ((100.0f - price)/100.0f);

            tR.setText(String.valueOf(pri));
            tRpay.setText(String.valueOf(per));

            tR.setText("" + pri);
            tRpay.setText("" + per);

            // catch
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // write a message to users
            tR.setText("");
        }
    }

});
```

}

Update:

I am using the SeekBar as a percent. So when I move the SeekBar there will be numbers 0-100 in the second TextView.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First I recommend using better variable names than pri and per. I would try printing the values of price and percent before you do any calculations just to be sure they are indeed correct.

Comment: As you know pri is for Price and per is for Percent!

Comment: `The First result is going well but the second is NOT!` What is first result and second result?

Comment: The first one is like the Discount and the second one is the Price to pay. for example if the main price is 100 and I have 60% discount the first result have to be 60 and the second one what I have to pay is 40.

Comment: @user3051834 I realize this but price and percent are already variables (with different values) hence why I said the names are ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, Thanks ... but I still using the same names :) bad habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
DiscountValue = price*discount/100.0f;  
ValueToPay = price - DiscountValue;
```